# Dangerous class initialization method?

Tags: c++, initialization

I use the following approach to automatically initialize a class that only has static methods (it's in a header-only library...) and should not be instantiated:

```
class Config {
public:
    Config() = delete; 
    static void someMethod_1() {}
    static void someMethod_2() {}
private:
    // Initialization method.
    static bool initialize()
    {
        // Do initialization here, look for processor cores for example...
        ...

        // Done.
        return true;
    }
    // Several static inline properties here...
    ...

    // The very last property in this class. All other properties should 
    // have been (default) initialized by now.
    static inline bool is_initialized = initialize();
}
```

As far as I know the initialization order is OK, it's thread safe (static init guarenteed to be done by one thread only since C++11?), but am I missing pitfalls?

Comment: It seems like you want to create a singleton class. If you really need one then I  recommend you look into [the Meyer's singleton](https://laristra.github.io/flecsi/src/developer-guide/patterns/meyers_singleton.html). And don't forget the copy/move constructors/assignment operators. But also please take some time to read [Singleton Considered Stupid](https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/singleton-considered-stupid). Singletons are seldom a good idea.

Comment: This [*monostate pattern*](https://wiki.c2.com/?MonostatePattern) is (as a C++ implementation) basically using `class Config` as a `namespace`.  Nothing wrong with the monostate pattern, but I'd argue in favor of a namespace with static members as being more idiomatically C++.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, thanks for the read-work. That singleton would need calls like `Config::instance().someMethod()` and initialization goes in the constructor? I liked the idea of simply writing `Config::someMethod()`. Testing if the class is initialized in every static method would also be possible, but less automatic for me...

Comment: Function local `static` variables have the thread safety guarantee, not class members

Comment: Namespaces could work, but it's possible for third-parties to add to the namespace which might not always be what you want. As for the `Config::instance().someMethod()` versus `Config::someMethod()` variants, you could still do the static functions variant, but each static function get the instance and then do what they need using that instance. Or each static function could be a wrapper that gets the instance and call the instance function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You could then call the instance() method, and leave it because all static members are then initialized by the constructor? Like: `int getInt(){ getInstance(); return intMember;}`. It would be a small refactoring from what I have now...

Comment: And, adding to my previous comment, I am tempted to replace `Config& getInstance()` by `void initConfig() { static Config; }` (less code for performance critical members when calling initConfig()) but then the static Config may be optimized away so that class init does not take place at all?

Comment: The direction you head is C-style ... bool good = config_initialize(); if (good) config_somemethod_1(); config_terminate();  ... that just using C++ syntax. Singleton (that is also not too good a thing) gets rid of several problems with it. Otherwise ... the compiler does not optimize away code in constructors (and so constructors) that it can't prove being worthless.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly according to the comments above, the following is a better approach (not tested, so may contain typos...):

```
class Config {
public:
    // Do something for the caller.
    static void someMethod()
    {
        // Make sure the class is initialized.
        initConfig();

        // Usual work, can use static members directly now.
        ...
    }
private:
    // Delete some.
    Config(const Config&) = delete;
    Config(const Config&&) = delete;
    Config& operator = (const Config&) = delete;
    Config& operator = (const Config&&) = delete;

    // Call this to initialize the class (once).
    const Config& initConfig()
    {
        static Config instance;
        return instance;
    }

    // Constructor which initializes the class.
    Config()
    {
        // Do initialization here, look for processor cores for example...
        ...
    }
    // Several static inline properties here, to be initialized...
    ...
}
```

Only question for me is if I am even allowed to write:

```
    // Call this to initialize the class (once).
    void initConfig()
    {
        static Config instance;
    }
```

without the `static Config instance;` being optimized away because the compiler does not see its relevance here.